# Extracting a symlinked zip file's content within a directory with same name as symlink

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zip, symlink

I have a zip file name `app.zip` which has multiple symlinks named `kafka.zip`, `hdfs.zip` etc. can be anything.

```
$ll
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xyz xyz    7 Mar  2 13:35 app.zip
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xyz xyz    7 Mar  2 13:35 hdfs.zip -> app.zip
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xyz xyz    7 Mar  2 13:23 kafka.zip -> app.zip
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xyz xyz    7 Mar  2 13:35 myapp.zip -> app.zip
```

When I extract any symlinked zip file, it creates a directory with the original file name, see below:

```
$ unzip kafka.zip 
Archive:  kafka.zip
   creating: app/
 extracting: app/my.properties       
 extracting: app/my.sh
```

I want it to be extracted with the symlink name, i mean if i am extrating kafka.zip then the directory name should be kafka instead of app.

Answer (score 0):

In the unzip command you can specify the folder:

```
unzip kafka.zip -d kafka
```

As I understand it you want this to happen automatically without the extra parameter so you could make a small script to run the unzip command, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
unzip $1 -d ${1%.zip}
```

Then run this:

```
myunzip.sh kafka.zip
```

Comment: That is also not an option. The end user should get a zip file and run `unzip filename.zip`

Comment: It might be an option to add something like alias unzip='myunzip' in your users system, I would rather not do that myself, but if it is exactly what you need in this case it could work

Comment: End user are unknown to me. Anything that I can do while creating the zip or symlink?

Comment: Don't think so, you could name your script unzip or (ln -s myunzip.sh unzip), but that would still not go all the way since ./unzip will be needed to execute it. Sorry but I'm starting to run out of ideas. You basically want to modify the behaviour of the unzip command but cannot modify the system it is on, right now I don't see how you could get closer than this.